# How to multiple 2 async function values Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have async functions in my services which return as follows.

**Questions**

1. What is the best way to do (**contractAddress*displayValue**) for every array item? and be able to display the returned value on the page.
2. What is the best way to store async data to an observable, be able to subscribe to it, and use the data further, is NGRX recommended here to manage the state?

   ```
   async getSanityTokens() {
        const coins = await fetch("https://i7ml51e6.api.sanity.io/v2021-10-21/data/query/production?query=*%5B_type%3D%3D'coins'%5D%7B%0A%20%20ContractAddress%2C%0A%20%20name%2C%0A%20%20usdPrice%0A%7D")
    const data = await coins.json();
    const address = data.result;
    return address
   }

   async getThirdWebTokens(contractAddress) {

     const  sdk = new ThirdwebSDK(
       new ethers.Wallet(
         environment.metamask_Key,
         ethers.getDefaultProvider('https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/94ef7ea56a0e4585834ffbb4dfb3f8b8'))
         )
         const token = sdk.getToken(contractAddress);
         const tokens = await token.balanceOf("0x47444Bfc280Bd50e3a96ccFd031f7539d6B6E97A")

         return tokens
   }

   async getTokens() {
     const coins = await this.getSanityTokens();
     const promises = coins.map(coin=>this.getThirdWebTokens(coin.ContractAddress));
     const tokenArray = await Promise.all(promises);
     return tokenArray
   }
   ```

When accessed I get the result  as follows

**this.coin.getSanityTokens().then(res=>console.log("this is sanity data",res));**

```
 this is sanity data 
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {ContractAddress: '0xBbCd8c1b5993062F2761CF07e27C2adebc55766F', name: 'Ethereum', usdPrice: '2088'}
1: {ContractAddress: '0xb74FbCF3b2e6b29B0b86f005FCC80eC649de7E30', name: 'Bitcon', usdPrice: '30947'}
2: {ContractAddress: '0x7a6DC36DD8CC525E15C2B14a415253153909fc24', name: 'Solana', usdPrice: '52'}
length: 3
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

**this.coin.getTokens().then(res=>console.log("this is thirdweb data",res));**

```
this is thirdweb data 
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {name: 'Ethereum', symbol: 'ETH', decimals: 18, value: BigNumber, displayValue: '8.0'}
1: {name: 'Bitcoin', symbol: 'BTC', decimals: 18, value: BigNumber, displayValue: '5.0'}
2: {name: 'Solana', symbol: 'SOL', decimals: 18, value: BigNumber, displayValue: '12.0'}
length: 3
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Combine the result of both `getThirdWebTokens` and `getSanityTokens`
   So inside change `getTokens` like this:

```
async getTokens() {
  const coins = await this.getSanityTokens();
  const promises = coins.map(coin => {
            const tokenValues = this.getThirdWebTokens(coin.ContractAddress);
            return {...coin, ...tokenValues, usdTotal: (+coin.usdPrice) * (+tokenValues.displayValue)
});
  const tokenArray = await Promise.all(promises);
  return tokenArray
}
```

2. In most cases if you have a basic application, NGRX may add some unnecessary overhead. Instead of adding it, you can simply declare a state service, which can be provided `inRoot` that stores the necessary data. Something like:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class StateService {
    private stateSubject = new BehaviorSubject<SomeModel>({});

    state$ = this.stateSubject.asObservable();

    get currentState(): SomeModel {
        return this.stateSubject.value;
    }

    setState(state: Partial<SomeModel>) {
        const oldValue = this.stateSubject.value;
        this.stateSubject.next(...oldValue, ...{state || {}});
    }
```

then when you need to read it from somewhere, just subscribe to `this.stateService.state$`.
And remeber to unsubscribe or use the async pipe afterwards.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. What you said about state service, looks a bit complex and I have no idea about it. I just want to be able to display the USD-TOTAL in HTML. so is there any easy way to do it? like Async pipe?

Comment: if you call `getTokens` within the same component, and want to display the total inside the component html, you can simply asign a variable, and directly display it. something like this:


`ngOnInit(): void {
   this.myTokens = await getTokens();
}

`

in html:
`<div *ngFor="let token of myTokens">
   {{token.usdTotal}}
</div>`

Comment: Ok thanks for the all help appreciate it